# Need BuildMaster releases to start at 1.0 -- not 0.0

Tags: buildmaster

When I create a new application, my releases are starting at 0.0.

I want them to start at 1.0.  Where might I set that?

I've checked all the documentation, app settings, etc, to no avail.  Using latest - 4.3.9.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0.0 release is merely a setup release, the number for that cannot be set. However, you can cancel that release and simply create a new one and enter in 1.0 for its release number.

Comment: Thanks.  Please consider updating the online documentation to explain this.